# Python: Como obter uma chave de um dicionário com base no valor?

Tags: python, dicionário

Eu tenho um dicionário no formato tabela={"t":148}
Eu consigo retornar 148 fazendo tabela["t"], certo?
Como eu posso fazer para retornar "t" com base no 148?
Quando eu tento printar tabela[148] acaba retornando "None", por que?

Answer (score 4):

A estrutura de dicionários foi criada com o intuito de rapidamente recuperar um **valor** a partir de uma **chave**

Sendo assim, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> tabela = {"t":148}

>>> tabela["t"]
148

>>> tabela[148]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 148
```

A exceção `KeyError` significa que a **chave** buscada não existe. Para que este erro não aconteça e você tenha mais controle em seu programa, você pode usar um `try/except` ou o método `get()` retornando um valor *default*. Veja abaixo

### try/except

```
try:
    valor = tabela[148]
except KeyError:
    print("Esta chave não existe")
```

### get

```
valor = tabela.get(148, "Esta chave não existe")
print(valor)
```

O resultado para ambos os casos será `Esta chave não existe`

### Respondendo sua pergunta

Para achar a chave usando o valor (considerando que os valores são únicos:

```
for chave, valor in tabela.items():
    if valor == 148:
       break
print(chave)
```

O resultado será `t`

Imaginando que a estrutura fosse algo como:

```
tabela = {"t": 148,
          "u": 200,
          "v": 148
         }
```

Perceba que as chaves "t" e "v" possuem valor 148.

Então, para recuperar múltiplas chaves a partir de um valor, poderia ser algo como:

```
resultado = []
for chave, valor in tabela.items():
    if valor == 148:
        resultado.append(chave)

print(resultado)
```

O resultado seria: `['t', 'v']`

**EM TEMPO**

Recuperar a chave a partir de um valor **NÃO DEVE** ser frequente em seu programa. Caso seja, a estrutura adotada está errada.

Espero ter ajudado.